# Calculate Previous Page Path in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am pulling data for a homepage heat map and I would like to only see *pageviews* where the previous page was the homepage.

My data is imported Google Analytics tables - the metric 'previous page path' does not exist in BQ, so how would I go about working it out?

Here is a basic example of my query:

```
SELECT
  hits.page.pagePath
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([***.ga_sessions_],
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -4, 'DAY'),
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
WHERE ? -- Where previous page path was the homepage?
GROUP BY hits.page.pagePath
```

What could I use in the WHERE clause to define the previous page path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your query you use the `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` function, I guess you are using legacy SQL. In this case, you can use the `LAG` function, which *Enables you to read data from a previous row within a window*. Therefore, if you order the pages of each session by their hit number (the window), you can get the previous page of each page.

The following query will do what you want:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT Page, count(*) as pageviews
FROM(
   SELECT hits.page.pagePath as Page, 
          LAG(hits.page.pagePath, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitId, date ORDER BY hits.hitNumber ASC) as PreviousPage
   FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([****.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -4, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
   WHERE hits.type='PAGE'
)
WHERE PreviousPage='/yourHomePage'
GROUP BY Page
-- ORDER BY pageviews desc
```

where you have to replace '/yourHomePage' with your actual homepage URI.

Comment: What if you open one link a in a new browser tab and then click on another link b? This way the hitNumber based query would not yield b as originating from the home page, although it did.

Answer (score 6):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT Page, COUNT(*) AS PageViews
FROM(
   SELECT hit.page.pagePath AS Page, 
          LAG(hit.page.pagePath, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitId, DATE ORDER BY hit.hitNumber ASC) AS PreviousPage
   FROM `your_ga_sessions_table`, UNNEST(hits) AS hit
   WHERE hit.type='PAGE'
)
WHERE PreviousPage='/yourHomePage'
GROUP BY Page
-- ORDER BY PageViews DESC
```

Also consider below version, where you can collect the whole path for each visitor/visit and than to filter by any given path patter with regular expressions

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId, 
  visitId,
  STRING_AGG(hit.page.pagePath, '>' ORDER BY hit.hitNumber) AS path
FROM `your_ga_sessions_table`, UNNEST(hits) AS hit
WHERE hit.type='PAGE'
GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitId
HAVING REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, r'/page1>/page1')
-- ORDER BY 1, 2
```

by properly constructing regex you can looks for any page sequence of any length  and order etc. to support for example funnel analysis